# lisp: building a list of lists from a single list

Tags: list, recursion, lisp

I am trying to take a list of 16 numbers I have and make it into a list of 4, 4 element sublists to represent the game board of a magic square. I made a method that can take a list and return a single sublist, and now I am trying to recursively use this method to build the full board.

My problem however, is my initBoard returns nil no matter what and I know every other method is working as desired. Any clarification of my error would be greatly appreciated!

Also here is an example input list:

(4 5 15 10 14 11 1 8 9 16 6 3 7 2 12 13)

And what I want as the output would be:

((4 5 15 10) (14 11 1 8) (9 16 6 3) (7 2 12 13))

```
(defun smallList (lst cnt)
   (cond ((>= cnt 4) nil)
   (t (cons (car lst) (smallList (cdr lst) (+ 1 cnt))))))

(defun isEmpty (lst)
   (if lst 1 -1))

(defun initBoard (lst)
   (cond ((= (isEmpty lst) -1) nil) 
   (t (cons (smallList lst 0) (initBoard  (cddddr lst))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your three functions and it gave me the correct output, so perhaps your issue isn't where you think it is.

```
(initBoard '(4 5 15 10 14 11 1 8 9 16 6 3 7 2 12 13))
```

=> `((4 5 15 10) (14 11 1 8) (9 16 6 3) (7 2 12 13))`

Comment: Well the once difference in what I have versus your example, I'm passing a list I defined with setq, is that perhaps causing some sort of issue? EDIT: that line you posted still returned nil, are you using clozure?

Comment: No, I'm using SBCL, but they're both standards compliant and this is standard code. I started up a blank REPL, pasted in the functions you gave me, and then ran that line.

Comment: I figured but I just wanted to check. That's super strange, seeing as the code posted is copy pasted directly from the code I wrote. Copy pasted the code back and it started working, thanks for proving it worked!

Comment: What other code have you loaded and what development environment are you using?

Comment: I have a few other functions for file IO and user input. I'm writting in lispbox, so emacs running clozure

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- `someList`, `lst`, `cnt` is not idiomatic, use `some-list`, `list`, `count`
- You don't need `is-empty`, just use `endp` or `null`, which returns a boolean (not -1 or 1). You could make an alias if you want (but why?):

  ```
  (setf (symbol-function 'is-empty) #'endp)
  ```

You could use a loop for `small-list`:

```
(defun small-list (list)
  (values (loop repeat 4 collect (pop list)) list))
```

The secondary value is the rest of the list, so that you don't need to `cddddr`.

But in fact, it might be better to initialize the whole board inside a single function:

```
(defun init-board (list)
  (loop repeat 4 collect
       (loop repeat 4 collect (pop list))))
```

The first `LOOP` collect lists of 4 elements, which are collected by the inner `LOOP`. The collected elements are popped from the input list. 
Now, if I wanted to be extremely careful, I would add some checks and report errors on bad inputs:

```
(defun init-board (list)
  (flet ((failure ()
           (error "Input list should contain exactly 16 integers: ~S"
                  list)))
    (loop
       with current = list
       repeat 4 collect
         (loop
            repeat 4
            collect (if current
                        (let ((element (pop current)))
                          (check-type element integer)
                          element)
                        (failure)))
       into board
       finally (if list (failure) (return board)))))
```

Also, I would use a multi-dimensional array for boards.

```
(make-array '(4 4) :initial-contents (init-board list))
```

Comment: I avoid using list since there is the function that is defined as list. Thanks for pointing out the way to avoid isEmpty. I would much rather use a 2d array and loops, but the assignment is asking for lists and recursion unfortunately.

Comment: @DShuler I understand, but just in case you come from a Scheme background, `(lambda (list) (list list))` works fine in CL and is not ambiguous at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following recursive function:

```
(defun smalllist (l n) 
   (when l 
      (cons (subseq l 0 (min n (length l))) 
            (smalllist (nthcdr n l) n))))
```